# SQL retrieve a "calendar" table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calendar, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables:

1. `BK_Athleten` with many columns but the 3 interesting ones are:

   - FINCode: the registration number of the athlete, primary key
   - Name
   - Surname
2. `BK_Einheiten` with many columns but the interesting 2 are:

   - IDEinheit: the index of the training session, primary key
   - Datum: the date of the session
3. `BK_Anwesend` with 3 columns which is a register of the training sessions

   - IDPres: just an index
   - FINCode: is the registration number of an athlete
   - IDEinheit: is the progressive index of the training sessions

How can I retrieve the monthly training attendance table? Passing the month to the function I would like 
to retrieve a table with the athlete name on the left and all the month days on the top and at the intersection the count
of the attended sessions per athlete and per day (even the days with 0 sessions should appear in the table).

Is it possible to achieve this without scalar querying the database per every single day and athlete?

UPDATE

Many thanks for the suggestions! I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

After many hours of attempts I'm getting stuck with the following error:

> The column prefix 'BK_Anwesend' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
>   The multi-part identifier "BK_Athleten.FINCode" could not be bound.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
AS
SELECT BK_Athleten.FINCode,   
 [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16],
  [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]   
FROM  

(SELECT        BK_Athleten.FINCode, RIGHT(BK_Einheiten.Datum, 2) AS Day
FROM            BK_Anwesend INNER JOIN
                         BK_Athleten ON BK_Anwesend.FINCode = BK_Athleten.FINCode INNER JOIN
                         BK_Einheiten ON BK_Anwesend.IDEinheit = BK_Einheiten.IDEinheit
GROUP BY BK_Athleten.FINCode, BK_Einheiten.Datum) AS SourceTable

PIVOT  
(  
Count(BK_Anwesend.IDPres) 
FOR Day IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], 
[16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31] )  
) AS PivotTable;
```

UPDATE 2

After the corrections of CBS

CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
 AS
 SELECT FINCode,

and in pivot clause also:

PIVOT
(
Count(IDPres)

now the error is "Invalid column name 'IDPres'". Tried every change but without success.

UPDATE 3

The view is now working!

CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
AS
SELECT FINCode, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
FROM  (SELECT        BK_Athleten.FINCode, RIGHT(BK_Einheiten.Datum, 2) AS Day, BK_Anwesend.IDPres
FROM            BK_Anwesend INNER JOIN
                         BK_Athleten ON BK_Anwesend.FINCode = BK_Athleten.FINCode INNER JOIN
                         BK_Einheiten ON BK_Anwesend.IDEinheit = BK_Einheiten.IDEinheit) AS PVT

PIVOT
(
Count(IDPres) 
FOR Day IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], 
[16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31] )
) AS PRT

I have now 2 questions:

1) How can I make the query dynamic depending on the number of days in the month?

2) How can I add 2 right columns with a) The sum of the sessions 2) the percentage of attendance depending on the last row of data?

Many thanks.

Comment: what DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL Something else? Solutions may differ depending on your platform. SQL has many variations across the different vendors. Also have you tried anything so far? Normally here we help with fixing bugs, rather than delivering whole pieces of functionality. We are not a free outsourcing service. To answer your exact question, "yes", it's almost certainly possible to achieve it, unless your DBMS is very limited. But somehow I suspect you didn't really just want "yes" or "no", you wanted the actual solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove table name from final select query.

```
 CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
 AS
 SELECT FINCode,
```

and in pivot clause also:

```
PIVOT  
(  
Count(IDPres)
```

This should fix your error.